# Django, GenericForeignKey is None when accessing an item of QuerySet result?

Tags: django, model

Suppose you have a generic foreign key in MyModel.

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, db_index=True, related_name='+')
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(db_index=True)
    target = generic.GenericForeignKey()
```

Is the target supposed to be None when you iterate queryset of this class?

```
for my_model in MyModel.objects.all():
   print my_model.target  # <-- this is None
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's supposed to give you the related object **if** it has one.

If you are sure it has one:

Try instead:

```
target = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
```

Comment: btw, Is there a way to filter out the instances that doesn't have the related object?

Comment: Try MyModel.objects.exclude(object_id=None)

Comment: I don't think it will work, I have data which has `object_id, content_type` but target is None.